# Can I add an event to Google Calendar from Google Search?

Tags: google-search, google-calendar

If I need to set a reminder, I can just google "*Remind me to get laundry in 1 hour*" and it will prompt me with the option to add it to my Google Calendar:

[image]

Is there a similar trick for adding an **event** rather than a **reminder**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar with calendar events. If you "search" for

```
add event dinner 11/30 6:00 pm
```

you'll get a prompt like this:

[image: "Create event" prompt]

You will, of course, need to be logged in to your Google Account, and the event will go to your default calendar. I imagine the same sort of terminology you can use in Google Calendar Quick Add is the same you'd use here. They keywords seem to be "add event" or "add meeting". There are probably others.

Comment: 5 years later, this no longer works. Or at least, your example search does not yield that prompt on my Google account in Firefox 120.